# Request.Forms.Keys.Count = 0 on Postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, http-post

I have the following HTML on my displayed form

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Edit User Roles</legend>
<ul>
    <% foreach (string role in (string[]) ViewData["roles"]){ %>
        <li>
            <div id="Div4" class="grid_6">
                <div id="Div5" class="grid_2 alpha" style="font-weight: bold;">
                    <%= Html.CheckBox("role." + role,  Roles.IsUserInRole(Model.UserName, role))%>
                </div>
                <div id="Div6" class="grid_3 omega" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt;">
                    <label for="role.<%: role %>">
                        <%: role %></label><br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
</fieldset>
```

I have the following code in my Controller

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditUser( string id, bool approved )
    {
        int i = Request.Form.Keys.Count 

        foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)
        {
            if (key.StartsWith( "role." ))
            {
                // Do something
            }
        }

        MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser( id );

        return View( membershipUser );
    }
```

If I break the code and explore, I find that the Request.Form.Keys.Count = 0, although there should be at least 4 keys created with "role." as a prefix from four checkboxes displayed on the form.

What am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Request.Form.Keys.Count = 0` could have two possible explanations:

- No value was sent in the POST body
- You used some special content type such as for example `application/json` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (could happen if you play with AJAX)

I would recommend you using [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see exactly what's contained in the POST request and if there are any values. You haven't shown the form definition neither how you are submitting it. If you are POSTing with AJAX maybe there's where the problem lies.

Here's an example of how a valid request might look like in FireBug:

[image]

Comment: I am submitting the form thus: `<% using (Html.BeginForm( "EditUser", "Admin", new { id = Model.UserName, approved = Model.IsApproved } )) { %> <input type="submit" value="Update User" /> <% } %>`  There is no AJAX or JSON used on the subform.   I have tried to use Firefox. It worked at first, but now I am getting the following: **The proxy server is refusing connections**.

Comment: @xiecs, the problems comes from the fact that your data is not inside the form but as part of the query string, so Request.Form will be empty. You could use `Request["approved"]` to fetch them.

Comment: So the problem seems to be the fact that I am using Html.BeginForm to generate my button correctly, which means I lose my Request.Form.Keys data from the rest of the form. I need to do it this way because I have a second BeginForm to generate another button. Why isn’t there an Html.Button object that would provide the flexibility required?